# SICP example doesn't work on Racket

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, racket

I am trying an example on Chapter 4 of SICP (part of writing the LISP interpreter)

```
(define (definition-value exp)
    (if (symbol? (cadr exp))
        (caddr exp)
        (make-lambda 
                    (cdadr exp) ; formal parameters
                    (cddr exp)  ; body
        )              
    )
) 


(define (make-lambda parameters body)
    (cons 'lambda (cons parameters body))
)
```

I Tested it, definition-value on '(define (double x) (+ x x))) should return a lambda function

```
( (definition-value '(define (double x) (+ x x))) 10)
```

Racket outputs

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: (lambda (x) (+ x x)); arguments were: 10
```

Isn't "(lambda (x) (+ x x))" a procedure? Or it is a reference? If it is a reference, any way to "dereference" it?

Answer (score 2):

`definition-value` returns the value in the *definition expression* given to it as an argument:

```
(definition-value '(define x 42))  
=> 42

(definition-value '(define (qq x) (+ x y 42))) 
=> (make-lambda '(x) '((+ x y 42)))
=> '(lambda (x) (+ x y 42))
```

You can't call the quoted list as a function, as you do: `( '(lambda (x) (+ x y 42)) 10)` is invalid. It is not a function, it is just an [s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).

`definition-value` is part of [an interpreter](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1). This interpreter is the way to "dereference", i.e. interpret function definitions. Different interpreters can have different ways to interpret same function definitions, giving different semantics to the resulting languages.

Evaluation of expressions must be done in context - they appear inside certain [lexical scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) (area in code where a variable is *visible*), which gives rise to [*environments*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding) (also, [*this*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28tech._environment%29)). In the example above, `y` is defined in some enclosing scope *in the program being interpreted*. Trying to interpret that expression in REPL by calling [Racket's `eval`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html), what value would `y` have?

Comment: So that is my first guess, definition-value returns a reference. However, I tried ( (eval '(lambda (x) (+ x x))) 10) => 20, this eval is the built-in eval.         But             (  (eval  (definition-value '(define (double x) (+ x x))) ) 10) => compile: unbound identifier (and no #%app syntax transformer is bound) at: lambda in: (lambda (x) (+ x x)). I am trying to learn this chapter, I know at the end I should have a working version of eval. However, this is really long and I would like to learn and test each function separately.

Comment: each function does what it does. `definition-value` manipulates s-expressions. Evaluating them is not part of its universe of discourse.

Comment: I am confused, if definition-value really returns an a s-expression '(lambda (x) (+ x x))) 10), the built-in eval function (nothing to do with definition-value any more once it returns a value) should be able to evaluate it, isn't it?

Comment: who knows what Racket does at its REPL? You can try to break it into two steps: `(setq x (definition-value '(define (double x) (+ x x))))`. and then, `((eval x) 10)`. What happens then? (but this tests `eval` as much as it tests `definition-value`; just inspecting the value of `x` should be enough for you here).

Comment: It actually works that way, (define x (definition-value '(define (double x) (+ x x)))), ((eval f) 10) =>20 and no error

Comment: see? :) but that has tested `eval`'s workings at the Racket REPL. Put that in a file, and it might have worked as you had it before. still, it's about Racket's `eval`, not yours. :) accept?

Comment: So I didn't have sicp version eval implemented yet, not even the definition. I am just confused that why  ( (eval (definition-value '(define (double x) (+ x x))) ) 10) => compile: unbound identifier (and no #%app syntax transformer is bound) at: lambda in: (lambda (x) (+ x x)). This is the built-in eval. I tried both REPL and file, it is the same.

Comment: Let me correct my previous comment,  ( (eval (definition-value '(define (double x) (+ x x))) ) 10) works at REPL bot doesn't work in file

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer, if execute a Racket script in file, racket interpreter doesn't know the namespace, however, the REPL knows it. The solution is to add this line at the beginning of the file

```
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
```

Then pass ns to eval when using it

```
(eval <what ever code reference here> ns)
```

That will make my above mentioned examples work.

Comment: the original question was "Isn't "(lambda (x) (+ x x))" a procedure?", not "how can I evaluate quoted lambda expressions?". You are supposed to ask a *new* question on SO when you change your mind.